# Spring MVC + Angular2: ZipFiles

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-mvc

I need some guidance here.

Soo I am building this app. Front Angular2 and Back Spring MVC.

I need to input a Zip file from my page (Angular), read it with spring, decompress and save it in a folder in my server...

Whats is the best and the correct way of doing it?

Also. Should I upload the file, save it (compressed) and then decompress. Or there is a way of upload and save the decompressed file.

This is my form. I will probably put and < input type="file"> on top of the create exercice button.

```
    <form #createExerciseForm="ngForm">
      <label for="exercise-name">Title</label>
      <div class="form-group" [class.error]="conflictErrorExercise">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
              id="exercise-name" 
              [(ngModel)]="currentExercise.name" 
              #name="ngModel"
              name="exercise-name" 
              required>
      </div>
      <label for="exercise-question">Question</label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" 
                  id="exercise-question"
                  [(ngModel)]="currentExercise.question" 
                  #name="ngModel"
                  name="exercise-question" 
                  required></textarea>
      </div> 
      <label for="exercise-question">Weight</label>
      <div class="form-group" [class.error]="weightErrorExercise">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" 
                  id="exercise-weight"
                  [(ngModel)]="currentExercise.weight" 
                  #name="ngModel"
                  name="exercise-weight" 
                  required>
      </div>     
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="exercise-commandbuild">Compilation command</span>
        <input type="text" 
              [(ngModel)]="currentExercise.commandbuild" 
              #name="ngModel"
              class="form-control"
              name="exercise-commandbuild">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="exercise-runcommand">Execution command</span>
        <input type="text" 
              class="form-control"
              [(ngModel)]="currentExercise.commandrun" 
              #name="ngModel"
              name="exercise-runcommand">
      </div>


      <button type="button" value="Upload" class="btn login-btn" [disabled]="!createExerciseForm.valid" (click)="addExercise()">Create Exercise</button>
    </form>
```